# Jquery's $('#element').on/off doesn't work after the second time

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-click-event

I have the following jQuery code (my first homemade jQuery code, so don't be too hard on me  :) ). 
Eveything works perfectly for the first time I use the toggles:

- I click on the right toggle, #content moves and left toggle appears.
- I click on the left toggle, #content moves back and right toggle appears. (everything is back to starting position).

But after that, my right toggle isn't clickable anymore (it does appear though). I would like to do the same thing over and over again ( click right toggle, #content moves etc etc). But with my current code, I'm only able to do this animation once.

Can anyone help me out :)?

Thanks in advance :)

```
    //starting values 
    $(".rowToggleL").off('click');    
    $(".rowToggleR").on('click'); 

    //Right Toggle
    $(".rowToggleR").click(function () {

        // make Toggle Right unclickable, make Toggle Left clickable
        $(".rowToggleR").off('click'); 
        $(".rowToggleL").on('click'); 


        //animate contentbox
        $("#content").animate({
            left: "-=300" // animate to the right
        }, 800, 

         // Animation complete. Make Toggle Right invisible, make Toggle Left visible 
        function() {
            $(".rowToggleR").css("display", "none");
            $(".rowToggleL").css("display", "inline");
        });


    });

    //Left Toggle
    $(".rowToggleL").click(function () {

        // make Toggle Left  unclickable, make Toggle Right clickable
        $(".rowToggleL").off('click');    
        $(".rowToggleR").on('click'); 

     //animate contentbox
        $("#content").animate({
            left: "+=300" // animate to the right
        }, 800, 

         // Animation complete. Make Toggle Left invisible, make Toggle Right visible.
        function() {
            $(".rowToggleL").css("display", "none");

            $(".rowToggleR").css("display", "inline");   
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of unnecessary code. You don't need the on and off. Also jquery has a hide and show function. This should work:

```
//Right Toggle
$(".rowToggleR").click(function() {
    //animate contentbox
    $("#content").animate({
        left: "-=300" // animate to the right
    }, 800,
            // Animation complete. Make Toggle Right invisible, make Toggle Left visible 
                    function() {
                        $(".rowToggleR").hide();
                        $(".rowToggleL").show();
                    });


        });

//Left Toggle
$(".rowToggleL").click(function() {
    //animate contentbox
    $("#content").animate({
        left: "+=300" // animate to the right
    }, 800,
            // Animation complete. Make Toggle Left invisible, make Toggle Right visible.
                    function() {
                        $(".rowToggleL").hide();
                        $(".rowToggleR").show();
                    });

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Because jQuery's on and off are not toggles for previously set handlers!

When you call `on()`, you add an handler (a function) to an event. But when you call `off()`, you remove **all** the handlers attached to an event.

When you call `on('click')`, you do not reactivate the handler you previously set with :

```
$(".rowToggleR").click(function () {});  // Which equals $(".rowToggleR").on('click', function () {});
```

But instead, you add another function to call when it's clicked.

Comment: I still have one problem though. I use boelensman1's code now, however I can still click the toggle twice, which results in a left += 600 or -=600 on the left position animation.

Comment: @Frank You can verify the actual position of your content, and move it only if it's in the expected position. You can also set a flag that will reflect the position of your content (like `currentProg = 'right' || 'center' || 'left'`)

Comment: Ah that's a smart workaround :) A flag is the same thing as a normal variable, right?

Comment: Yes it is! Don't forget to instantiate it out of your `click()`, it have to be shared between your two binds' scopes :)